# Regarding fetching data from database in android application

Tags: android, sqlite

I am developing an android application in which I have created a database named *HeadShop*. When I run the code it is crashing. Below is the crash report:

```
09-02 14:29:36.441: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14984): java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.redorange.database/com.redorange.database.HeadshopDatabaseActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table HeadTable already exists: create table HeadTable( _id integer primary key autoincrement, Name text not null, Grade text not null, Description text not null);
09-02 14:29:36.441: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14984):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1622)
09-02 14:29:36.441: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14984):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1638)
```

Can anyone help me in this regard?

I have coded acc to sqlite example.

Comment: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its crashing because you are trying to create a table that already exists. Modify your create table query.

```
CREATE [TEMPORARY] TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] tbl_name
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

Comment: should i paste my code here..so that u can have a look,,,,its not even writing the database...

Comment: @user813953 You should generally post your code here at StackOverflow, as a part of your question. So anyone could help to solve your issue.

Comment: @user813953 just edit your question and add the code. Not sure if you can edit your post after accepting an awnser though.